# AngularJS Routes and Resolve with new Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use the new Firebase with the Auth system and restricting routes in my `$routeProvider` via `resolves`.

However, I'm not quite understanding.

This is what I have. In my .config function, I am defining routes and initializing firebase. The following is in my config block.

```
$routeProvider
   .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.ejs',
      //resolve. this needs restricted
   })
   .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.ejs'
   })

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

I have found on the new docs site that these functions are available that are listed in my `.run()` block for angular.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.authentication = firebase.auth();

    /*firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if(user) {
            $rootScope.user = user;
        } else {
            $rootScope.user = false;
            $location.path('/login')
        }
    })*/

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user) {
        $rootScope.user = user;
    } else {
        $rootScope.user = false;
        console.log('No User!');
        $location.path('/login');
    }
})
```

Now, what I have above is only firing `every other time` I access any url on my site.

So my question is, how do I take what's in my .run() function and make it into a resolve for my routeProvider so I'm able to restrict routes again.

With the old firebase you would just call $firebaseAuth() like below and have a routeChangeError function that was called like the following.

```
// In config block. **old way**
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.ejs',
            resolve: {
                "currentAuth": ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
                    var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl);
                    var authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref);

                    return authObj.$requireAuth();
                }]
            }
        })
```

And then the routechangeerror in the .run() block.

```
 // .run block **old way**
 .run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, eventObj) {
        if (eventObj === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
            console.log('auth required!');
            $location.path("/login");
        }
    });
})
```

This doesn't work anymore because you aren't using `$firebaseAuth()` anymore. or `new Firebase(fbUrl);` for that matter either.

**UPDATE**

I feel like it's a bit messy but looking into routes a little more, I came up with this.

In my route resolve:

```
.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.ejs',
            resolve: {
                userAuthenticated: ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
                    var deferred = $q;
                    if(firebase.auth().currentUser) {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject();
                        console.log('Really!?');
                    }
                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
            }
        })
```

And then a simple routeChangeError.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
        alert("Not authorised");
})
```

The only problem is, it appears the deferred.promise is returning undefined. It's not activating the routeChangeError function. Even though my `console.log()` is getting called.

Could this be because `firebase.auth().currentUser` returns null when no user is authenticated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods have been renamed to `$waitForSignIn()` and `$requireSignIn`.

You can also use the `$firebaseRefProvider` service to configure your Database URL so it automatically configures the `$firebaseAuthService`.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseDatabaseUrl', '<my-firebase-url>')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', HomeController)
  .config(function($firebaseRefProvider, FirebaseDatabaseUrl, $routeProvider) {
     $firebaseRefProvider.registerUrl(FirebaseDatabaseUrl);
     $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "HomeCtrl",
        templateUrl: "views/home.html",
        resolve: {
          // controller will not be loaded until $waitForSignIn resolves
          "firebaseUser": function($firebaseAuthService) {
            return $firebaseAuthService.$waitForSignIn();
          }
        }
      }).when("/account", {
        controller: "AccountCtrl",
        templateUrl: "views/account.html",
        resolve: {
          // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
          "firebaseUser": function(Auth) {
            // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError
            return $firebaseAuthService.$requireSignIn();
          }
        }
      });
  });

function HomeController($scope, $firebaseRef, firebaseUser) {

}
```

Comment: I don't know what version or third party dependency you are using but this doesn't work at all for me, nor look like anything I've found on documentation. When I try to load the firebase module into my app I get an error that it's not defined. So, what third party are you using?

Comment: You also don't define your url like that anymore, you initialize firebase using a code block provided from Firebase. My question wasn't about third party dependencies.

Comment: I work on the Firebase team and I'm a maintainer of AngularFire. I wrote the `$firebaseRefProvider` and `$firebaseAuthService` features. It's a way to handle dependency injection with Database References. We're working on the docs for it. Check the docs on github for the authentication methods: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md.

Comment: Then if you work for firebase why do I have to initialize firebase by providing my URL's and THEN define it in Angular? Seems redundant.

Comment: If you register the URL it provides DI and automatically creates the Auth service for you. If you don't you use the firebase object as a global variable. With DI you have better testing and one less service to write. You should try the code and you'll see that these services do exist.

Comment: If I add AngularFire. I did get it to work. But now when I access my dashboard I receive this error : http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/cpws

Comment: @David - Thanks! I got my app to work with the code sample from github project -> https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md#ngroute-example. Though am using ui-router, I wanna know, why should we use pass FirebaseDatabaseUrl in the config?

Comment: @DavidEast I'm having a similar issue, would you be able to spare a few mins to take a look?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839404/how-to-secure-angular-routes-with-firebase-v3

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if it's the cleanest cut code on the globe but it works.

Firebase now provides a new function for getting the current user authenticated if there is one. After you initialize firebase, you have access to this function. `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

(This function returns user details if logged in and null if not)

So, in your route, you would create and resolve a promise based on the results of this function. Be sure to define deferred as `$q.defer();` (I struggled with this as you can see in my question update)

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.ejs',
            resolve: {
                userAuthenticated: ["$http", "$q", function($http, $q) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    if(firebase.auth().currentUser) {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject('NOT_AUTHORIZED');
                    }
                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
            }
        })
```

And then in your run function for Angular, you'll watch for route change errors.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
   $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
      if(rejection == 'NOT_AUTHORIZED')
      {
         $location.path('/login');
      }
    })
})
```

In the function above, you simply watch for an error in the route change. If the rejection is equal to 'NOT_AUTHORIZED' (passed in our rejection function in the resolve function) then we redirect the user to the login screen to become authenticated.

NOTE: In this routeChangeError function, you are free to do what you like maybe even show a little growl that the user is not authorized.