# Authenticating Angularfire with Firebase 3.0 SDK

Tags: angularjs, oauth, angularfire

I'm using "the new Firebase" for my AngularJS app, and I need to set up authentication to identify my users. I am using the AngularFire plugin, but the docs haven't been updated to the new SDK. I've cobbled together these few lines which seems like it works, but does nothing once authenticated.

```
auth.$signInWithPopup("google").then(function(data) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", data);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Authentication failed:", error);
    })
```

Neither callback in the "then" promise are running, and I'm getting nothing logged in the console, however I do get a prompt to grant access to your Google account. When I log the entire block of code, this is what I get:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
  $$state: Object
    status: 0
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Apparently `status: 0` means it's pending, that's all I can gather from the promise

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692046/angularjs-routes-and-resolve-with-new-firebase-auth