# $requireSignIn() not a function

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an angular app where am using Firebase for the authentication.

All the functionality is working fine except the `requireSignIn()` function.
I am calling the `requireSignIn()` in the following way:

Controller Code

```
 when('/success', {
      templateUrl: 'views/success.html',
      controller: 'SuccessController',
      resolve: {
        currentAuth: function(Authentication) {
          return Authentication.requireAuth();
        } //current Auth
      }
```

`Authentication` that I have above in the code is a service from which I am calling `requireSignIn()` function.

Authentication Code:

```
return{    
requireAuth:function(){
                    return auth.$requireSignIn();
                }
}
```

I am sharing the stack trace that I am getting after all this.

```
Error: auth.$requireSignIn is not a function
.requireAuth@file:///E:/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Exercise%20Files/ch01/01_04/angularregistration/js/services/authentication.js:55:21
.resolve.currentAuth@file:///E:/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Exercise%20Files/ch01/01_04/angularregistration/js/app.js:33:18
h/<.invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:41:374
m/</<@file:///E:/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Exercise%20Files/ch01/01_04/angularregistration/js/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js:11:82
q@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:8:1
m/<@file:///E:/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Ex_Files_AngularJS_Registration/Exercise%20Files/ch01/01_04/angularregistration/js/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js:11:28
e/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:130:409
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:103
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:142:165
uf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:145:399
Sd/</<.compile/<.pre/p@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:264:82

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js
Line 117
```

Help would be much appreciated as I am stuck for hours on this and can't find a reasonable solution.

Comment: what is `auth` ? is it defined in `Authentication `?

Comment: var auth = firebase.auth(); @DMCISSOKHO

Answer (score 0):

```
when('/success', {
  templateUrl: 'views/success.html',
  controller: 'SuccessController',
  resolve: {
    "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
    return Auth.$requireSignIn();
  }]
  }
```

and factory

```
.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
 return $firebaseAuth();
}
]);
```

also don't forget to inject currentAuth in your coltroller .. maybe it will work :)

Comment: did you get same error ? also go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692046/angularjs-routes-and-resolve-with-new-firebase-auth