# How to secure Angular routes with Firebase v3?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I want to protect various routes on my site using Firebase V3, AngularJS and ui.router.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37692046/angularjs-routes-and-resolve-with-new-firebase-auth) looks like a similar issue. I've followed the steps from that SO post but its not working for me.

**What I expect to happen:**
When clicking the FAQ link I should be forwarded to the login page if logged out and should display the FAQ page when logged in.

**What actually happens:**
FAQ page isn't accessible at all.  Logging in doesn't make any difference.  It also doesn't forward me to the login page when logged out.

I'm getting this error within my `run` function.

```
ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined(…)
```

I've included AngularFire on the page, if I don't I get a module injector error even if I remove Firebase from the dependency array.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'firebase']);
app.constant('FirebaseDatabaseUrl', 'https://myfbdb.firebaseio.com');
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $firebaseRefProvider, FirebaseDatabaseUrl) {
    $firebaseRefProvider.registerUrl(FirebaseDatabaseUrl);
// If a route other than status is requested,
// go to the auth route
//$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/logintest/login');

$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController as login'
    })

    .state('faq', {
        url: '/faq',
        templateUrl: 'pages/faq.html',
        controller: 'FaqController as faq',
        resolve: {
          // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
          "firebaseUser": ["$firebaseAuthService", function($firebaseAuthService) {
            console.log('waitForSignIn')
                    // $waitForSignIn returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                    return $firebaseAuthService.$waitForSignIn();
            }]
          } 

    })
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController as about',
        resolve: {
          // controller will not be loaded until $requireSignIn resolves
          "firebaseUser": ["$firebaseAuthService", function($firebaseAuthService) {
            // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError
            return $firebaseAuthService.$requireSignIn();
          }]
        }           
    })

});



app.controller('FaqController', ['$scope', 'firebaseUser', function($scope, firebaseUser){
console.log('faq')
}]);





app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
  console.log('run');
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
 // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireSignIn promise is rejected
 // and redirect the user back to the home page
 if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    console.log('redirecting to login page')
   $state.go("login");
 }
 });
  }]);
```

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of AngulsrFire. What is your version number?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply.  I'm using v1.2.0.

Comment: That would be the problem. Upgrade to 2.0+

Comment: Yes it is, thank you so much, upgraded to 2.0.2 and it now works - my apologies.  I've spent ages on it *sigh* lol ...... I think I saw as being deprecated on the site and didn't think about it being upgraded.

Comment: It'd all good! I added an answer to close it out :)

Comment: Nice one, thank you again.  2:25am here, I can go to bed now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularFire versions 2.0+ are compatible with Firebase 3.0. Anything below AngularFire 2.0 is for the legacy version of Firebase.